# MS Excel Filter Chart Data Labels not updating with filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, statistics, pivot-chart

I have a large table of data containing my x-axis data, a column of dates, a column of numbers, and a column of data labels. I have setup a pivot chart where the date is the filter and the data all updates when I change the filter, however when I change the filter the data labels do not change.

Is there any way to make the filter affect the data labels? I would have assumed that because the column was selected it would filter the same way the actual data does?

I am creating a statistical summary and the data levels are the LMS significance indicators, so I really need them to update with the data because this pivot chart will provide about 50 charts when completed and I don't want to have to manually label each one.

EDIT:
I tried the solution posted here: [Excel chart formatting lost when Refresh All or individual Right Click on Data > Refresh](https://superuser.com/questions/1371224/excel-chart-formatting-lost-when-refresh-all-or-individual-right-click-on-data?rq=1)

And the data labels all appeared correctly if I zoomed in far enough to see them, but as soon as I applied a filter the data labels all defaulted to the first set present in the table.

EDIT 2:

Here is the dataset.
[image: Dataset]

Pivot chart sorted for the first sample event (date). The data labels are pulled from the "Sig" column of the data table and are correct.

[image: correct labels]

But when I sort for the next sample event in the table, the data values update but the label values stay the same. Note the two blank entries in the middle of the table.

[image: incorrect labels]

I need the labels to update with the filter. In the data label options, "Label Contains: Value From Cells" is selected and the table column is selected. This table has 73 sample events so I can't go through and manually select the range for each label set.

Comment: a visual example might help

Comment: I'll add one when I get in the office in the morning.

Comment: Could you provide a picture about your problem?